# Hibernate Spatial: cache lookup failed for type

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, postgis

I have exactly the same error as in this e-mail thread:
http://hibernate-spatial.1140993.n2.nabble.com/cache-lookup-failed-for-type-1185046-tt7572634.html#a7572637 (unfortunately no solution there)

I want to persist an entity with a Geometry field using HibernateSpatial/Hibernate. On persist it throws an exception `'Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cache lookup failed for type 3178753'` (the type id changes with every request and is not contained in pg_type or pg_class).

Like the guy in the thread, I can:

- persist an entity where the Geometry field is NULL
- SQL INSERT the entity including the geometry field manually (using the generated query in the prepared statement `insert into tableA (id, polygon) values (1, 'SRID=4326;POLYGON((0 0,1 1,0 1,0 0))') RETURNING *`

The field definition is:

```
@Column(name = "polygon")
@Type(type="org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
private Geometry geom;
```

I also tried type Polygon (always the com.vividsolutions.jts... classes)

I use

- hibernate 4.3.11
- hibernate-spatial 4.3
- postgresql-9.4

In the DB the field is declared as geometry.

edit: it seems to be related to running the CREATE EXTENSION postgis call in one connection and the other one not picking those objects up, I don't know enough about PostgreSQL internals for that though